# On doing composer install getting error for private repo

Tags: composer-php

When trying to clone my private repos ;

[RuntimeException]

Failed to clone git@github.com:myOrganization/myRepo.git via git, https, ssh protocols, aborting.

git://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git
Cloning into '/Users/yus/Desktop/websites/h-s/vendor/xx/cache-bundle/xx/CacheBundle'...
fatal: remote error:
Repository not found.
https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git
Cloning into '/Users/yus/Desktop/websites/h-svendor/xx/cache-bundle/xx/CacheBundle'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myOrganization/myRepo.git'
git@github.com:.myOrganization/myRepo.git

Cloning into '/Users/yus/Desktop/websites/h-s/vendor/xx/cache-bundle/xx/CacheBundle'...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Does a manual `git clone git@github.com:myOrganization/myRepo.git` work for you?

As far as I can tell, you have not setup an oauth token, and the ssh key it is attempting to use is not valid for the repository you are trying to access. So there is no way for Composer to access your private repository.